# My computer suffers, however has enough resources

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, performance

I am so desperate with my PC as it is insufficent to run 7-8 tabs with Chrome sametime. It has SSD and other resources are like it is on below picture. It is taken while Chrome was suffering.

- Will internet connection speed make Chrome unresponsive?
- Is my processor too old for today's technology?

Thanks for your comments!

[image: My PC resources]

Comment: Chrome shouldn't be using 75% cpu just to browse the web.  A first generation i5 might not be great, but it should be more than capable.  show the process list sorted by CPU.

Comment: 75% was just a moment peak with total usage. I saw Chrome to use 20%-30% at most. When the PC was unsresponsive, I still see there are much available resources but nobody uses yet, instead it suffers.

Comment: A slow internet connection will not cause Chrome to become unresponsive.  That is an indication Chrome is using to many CPU resources or there isn't enough available for Chrome (thus Windows is making it wait)

Comment: Does it always suffer on particular sites or is it any site? Do you get the same problem with Firefox or Internet Explorer?

Comment: It is possible that one of your Chrome extensions could be causing a problem. Try disabling them (or at least listing them here).

Comment: I experience all the time and I couldn't stand no more and decide to ask gurus here. I have that with Firefox, too. I don't use many extensions  but, maybe just one of them causes it. Still it is too weird to have this while have many free resources.

Comment: @Kemal exactly, it seems odd, hence my line of questioning. *Something* is causing it to choke, and I'm giving options and potentials. You can edit your question to provide specific details.

Comment: @Mokubai I tried disabling extensions and applied suggestions here (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/speed-up-chrome-by-changing-these-8-flags/) it look it runs better now. Maybe LastPass has little negative effect over performance as it looks for input boxes all the time. Thank you Makubai

Comment: Lastpass isn't the source of your performance problems.

Comment: @Ramhound maybe tuneups made it better for now. I also cleared cache. It always makes performance better for a while after clearing cache. Thanks!

Comment: Those types of programs are major Snake Oil.

Comment: Reboot it, it's been running 15 days.

Comment: @Tetsujin that was a good one :) I mostly hibernate PC so it looks so long. I will try that too. Thx